# Is it even possible to make this loop wait a few seconds each time?

Tags: java, jsp, sleep

Firstly, yes I'm calling this from a web browser. It's quite a long piece of code but I've tried shortening it as much as possible.

Basically, I need to wait let's say 1 second for every iteration in the loop. Tried pretty much everything (.sleep() etc.) but it just doesn't seem to be pausing. The reason why I need to do this is because the SimpleSocketClient is calling a socket which has a low limit per second allowed.

```
    @Override
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String forwardToJsp = null;
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                String allUrls = request.getParameter("domains");
                ArrayList domainList = new ArrayList<String>();
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(allUrls);
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = sc.nextLine();
                    domainList.add(line);

                    // process the line
                }
                sc.close();
                String pageHtml = null;
                String domain = "";
                String status = "";
                String registrant = "";
                String dates = "";
                String tag = "";
                String email = "";
                ArrayList domains = new ArrayList<Domain>();
                Domain theDomain;

                String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
                if (ipAddress == null) {
                    ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < domainList.size(); i++) {

                    //NEED TO WAIT 1 SECOND HERE / ANYWHERE IN LOOP



                    String singleDomain = domainList.get(i).toString();



                    SimpleSocketClient tester = new SimpleSocketClient(singleDomain,ipAddress);
                    pageHtml = tester.getResult();

                    try {

                        String whoIs2 = ipAddress + " " + ipAddress + " " + singleDomain + "\r\n";

                        byte[] data = whoIs2.getBytes();





                        //details of each domain

                        //domain name
                        domain = singleDomain;

                        //status

                        status = "FTR";


                        //registrant

                         registrant = "N/A";


                        //dates

                            dates = "N/A";


                        //tag

                            tag = "N/A";


                        //email

                            email = "N/A";

                        }



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Logger.getLogger("ip is " + ipAddress + bulkWhoIsCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                        forwardToJsp = "index.jsp";
                        return forwardToJsp;
                    }

                    //single one
                    theDomain = new Domain(domain,status,registrant,dates,tag,email);


                    //now add to arrayList
                    domains.add(theDomain);
//                try {
//                    Thread.sleep(230000);
//                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                        Logger.getLogger(bulkWhoIsCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//                }
//                try {
//                    pause.poll(100 * 300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
//                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                        Logger.getLogger(bulkWhoIsCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//                }




                }
```

EDIT - Friend recommended to use ajax to poll updates but surely there's a way of just using java.

Comment: What was wrong with Thread.sleep(1000); for 1 second?

Comment: @Cruncher My guess: `Thread.sleep(1)` was tried.

Comment: @Gliptal wrong, `Thread.sleep(230000);` was tried. Read the code first.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed I wasn't the only one making these stupid errors.

Comment: What about Thread.currentThread().sleep(millis);?

Comment: @Andi `sleep` is `static` method, you can use `Thread#sleep` directly, as OP already tried but didn't work.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @Andi `Thread.currentThread().sleep()` will call the exact same method as `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` ought to work — I wrote a servlet just yesterday that sleeps in a loop (for debugging) and had no problems.  What happens when you try to step through the sleep call in a debugger?

Comment: For giggles you could try `Thread.currentThread().join(1000)`.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is the way to do it. If it's not working, then OP should figure out why. And sleeping for 30 or 230 seconds inside a servlet request is nuts. Maybe your container is interrupting the thread for taking too long.

Comment: Thread.sleep(1000) was tried too guys, just in case you think I started with 230000!

Comment: You will find, as you gain more experience, that `sleep` is evil -- only a little less evil than sitting in a tight loop waiting for seconds to tick by.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah saw that mentioned a good bit. I'm lost as to why it doesn't work as expected. See the socket won't allow a lot of calls every second so I need to do this.

Comment: The problem is that in many cases your code is called from within a thread that is performing several activities in sequence.  Sometimes it is "the" UI thread or "the" communications thread, etc.  In such a situation, when you `sleep`, you stop everything else in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your can try to set a while-loop in the while-loop, to pause it. Should like this:

```
 while(!done)
 {
     long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
     while(System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 1000L){}
 }
```

Didn't test it but the approach counts. I had the idea to do a combination of both. So every time Thread.Sleep() crashes, you have to take the loop. Something like this:

```
while(!done)
{
     long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
     try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
         System.err.println(e);
     }
     while(System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 1000L){}
}
```

When Thread.Sleep() worked it just get called once. Otherwise you need some CPU time. Could be the cpu economical version.

Comment: This may work, but it'll use lots of CPU repeatedly checking the current time.

Comment: True, depents how often you'l do that.

Comment: JIT will optimize this at runtime and the code execution will be faster than when it was executed at first.

Comment: So that while inside my for (int i=0) etc?

Comment: Have no idea what you want to do but it looks like it is on the right place there.

Comment: could be that GetTime() is the wrong method. Try other one have no possibility to check it out.

Comment: it wouldn't be getMilliseconds would it

Comment: Ask google or have a look in the Java API. I know C# has soemthing like StopWatch. Maybe there is something similar.

Comment: @user3504452 System.currentTimeMillis(). Peter:, I edited the correct API into your answer.

Comment: @user3504452 I promise you this code WILL wait. If it's still not doing what you want the problem is happening in another thread.

Comment: @Cruncher I'm not using threads / know much about them so you're probably right. The socket gets called in the SimpleSocketClient class though, not in the loop itself. does this matter?